# Writing commands to a file from a shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to write some lines of commands to a file, but some commands written in `$(...)` being evaluated. I want `$(...)` this to preserve.

I have tried following:

```
cat > .git/hooks/pre-commit << EOM
#Colors
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

# Javascript unit tests 
res=$(script -q /dev/null ./tests/hooks/non-ui-test-hook )
RESULT=$?
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && echo -e "$res" && exit 1
echo -e "All test cases passed.\n"
exit 0
EOM
```

It writes in file following content:

```
#Colors
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

# Javascript unit tests
res=Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: test
No test files found
RESULT=1
[  -ne 0 ] && echo -e "" && exit 1
echo -e "All test cases passed.\n"
exit 0
```

How can i preserve `$(...)` in output file?

Comment: What do you mean preserve it? What's your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alternatively escape `$`:

```
\$(...)
\$
```

in your code:

```
cat > .git/hooks/pre-commit << EOM
#Colors
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

# Javascript unit tests 
res=\$(script -q /dev/null ./tests/hooks/non-ui-test-hook )
RESULT=\$?
[ $RESULT -ne 0 ] && echo -e "$res" && exit 1
echo -e "All test cases passed.\n"
exit 0
EOM
```

Comment: it solved the issue, thanks. I have one more issue. I am using `res=$(script -q /dev/null mocha $(find "tests/non-ui" -name "*.js"))` command to run my test cases and get command output but it is returning only last line of test case result.

Comment: Your question is a little bit fuzzy to me :) ask it as another question provide more details the output you desire and the output you get so more people can help you... ;)

Comment: Escape AND quote the variables.  `res="\$(script -q /dev/null ./tests/hooks/non-ui-test-hook )"`

Answer (score 2):

Quote the end indicator of the here document, `EOM` in your case:

```
cat > .git/hooks/pre-commit << 'EOM'
...
...
EOM
```

Escaping using double quotes or backslash would do too:

```
cat > .git/hooks/pre-commit << "EOM"
...
...
EOM
```

Or

```
cat > .git/hooks/pre-commit << \EOM
...
...
EOM
```

---

You might have not noticed but `RESULT=$?` also got expanded to `RESULT=1` i.e. the exit status of `script...` inside the command substitution.

Just for the sake of completeness, if you want some expansion to happen but not others, you need to follow what you have currently and escape the ones you want to preserve with typical escaping methods.